# Retract duplicate flag

Tags: discussion, bug, flags, duplicate-questions

There is a post that's marked as duplicate: [A spell checker in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152484/a-spell-checker-in-java)

But the question that's *duplicate of above post* is deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151888/spell-checker-in-java

So shouldn't the duplicate mark be retracted?

Comment: The dupe target was a poor version of the same post by the same user.. It seems to  be "RemovedAbandonedClosed"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically: Yes, it should probably be re-opened because the target is deleted.
But ***only*** to close it again as *"unclear"*. (Which is a waste of everyone's time)

Both questions are asked by the same user. The newer question is a re-post of the older one, after the older one got closed.

That's why the newer one was closed as a duplicate of the old one. It is an *exact* duplicate, and a poor question to boot.